# Python-CV2: Problems with recorded video speed

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to use python to record a video through my webcam and it all goes perfectly except for the part where the length of the saved video doesn't match the actual time length of the recording. 
If I record a 10sec video, the saved video will have 6 or 12 or 15 seconds (random examples). After some research I've come to realize it has to do my webcam's fps value and I've worked on it but it didn't do the trick.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while (int(time.time() - start_time) < 10):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret == True:
        frames.append(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')) or get_drives() == default:
            break
    else:
        break
end_time = time.time() - start_time
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
save_frames_as_video(frames, end_time)
```

(1) First of all, I don't understand why, if I run my program several times, it sometimes generates a different number of total frames. For instance, I just ran it twice and for the first run it generated 2192 frames while in the second run it generated 1648 frames. Shouldn't it generate the same number of frames, given it's the same length of time and the same camera?

```
def save_frames_as_video(video, end_time):
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
   out = cv2.VideoWriter(VIDEO_FILE_NAME, fourcc, ____, (640, 480))
   for frame in video:
       out.write(frame)
   out.release()
```

(2) I have no idea what to put in the fps parameter (blankspace). I've tried 20.0 as a default value to no good result. Then I tried dividing the total number of frames for the length of the recording because I figured if it captured 200 frames and the length of the recording was 10sec, then the fps should be 20. It also didn't work. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried writing the frames to the output video while recording? Does that causes problems as well?

Comment: Writing directly to the output? That was my first approach and causes the same problem :\